# Confluent Kafka: Spring cloud kstream config to consume json and produce avro configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring cloud kstream app, that consumes a json message from input topic and transforms and produces an avro message to output topic.

A function processRecord takes Kstream<String, TestJson> and outputs KStream<String, TestAvro>

The consumer value serde would need to be io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerde and json.value.type would be TestJson

The producer value serde would be io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde

The schema registry would store the json and avro schemas.

Is there an example of how to do this, in particular the kstream configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the JSONSchema one as the default serde. Then consume the source topic

Use `.map()` function with `Produced.with()` and set the Avro Serde as the value serde, followed by `.to()` DSL function to write to the new topic.